# wxToolBar behavior on OSX

Tags: macos, wxpython, wxwidgets

It seems that wxToolBar is not behaving like native OSX apps does.
[wxToolbar http://img15.imageshack.us/img15/5683/screenshot20091208at947.png](http://img15.imageshack.us/img15/5683/screenshot20091208at947.png)

In most native OSX apps, you can drag the window around by dragging the toolbar, where the space is not occupied by buttons. In wxWidgets apps I can only move the window by dragging the title bar. Is there some way to fix that in wx(python)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is a known bug which you can view at http://trac.wxwidgets.org/ticket/10601
Perhaps using an older wx may work, but you may require newer functionality.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, now I know it's a bug at least.